# help with the probability of acceptance of a Nondeterministic Pushdown automata

Tags: context-free, probability-theory, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

I have this nondeterministic pda:
$$\Sigma=  \{a,b,c\}$$

and

$$
L=\{\omega\  \epsilon\ \Sigma^*\ |\ \omega\ = \alpha\beta\beta^R\gamma\ and\ \alpha,\beta,\gamma\ \epsilon\ \Sigma^*\ and\ |\beta|\ >3 \}
$$

So once i have create the NPDA, i have to calculate the probability of accepting a correct word, i know it depends on the size of $\alpha$ and the "free" jumps ($\varepsilon,\varepsilon->\varepsilon$).
My problem is that i can't find the exact function of probability can someone explain me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: PDAs are not a probabilistic model of computation. A PDA for a language $L$ *always* accepts every string $w\in L$ and *always* rejects any string not in $L$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby when i said probability i mean that since the desing of this pda is a nondeterministic one given a word accepted by this language, the language has to make two "guesses" so it won't always give a "true" answer. 
So i'm asking how probable is that it says that a given word it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when constructed in a natural way, you have to guess the correct position of $\beta$, so you have to have two positions right.

But there is a catch. In fact $L$ can alternatively be defined as $\{\omega \mid \omega = \alpha\beta\beta^R\gamma \text{ and } |\beta|=4 \}$. This is seen as folows: if you find any substring $\beta\beta^R$ then the central part of length 4+4=8 will also satisfy the palindromic substring constraint. So, $L$ is regular, and one can find a DFA for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing probabilistic about nondeterminism.  A nondeterministic machine is defined to accept a word $w$ if any of the possible sequences of "guesses" leads to acceptance, and to reject only if all possible sequences of guesses reject.

Perhaps you meant to ask about the proportion of the computation paths that accept. However, in this case, the question is ill-defined. The proportion of accepting paths depends not on the language but on the exact machine that is being used to accept it.  Any language that is accepted by some machine in a class (e.g., DFAs, PDAs, Turing machines) is accepted by infinitely many different ones.

As Hendrik Jan points out in his answer, the language $L$ you ask about is, in fact, regular. This means that one of the machines that accepts it is a deterministic finite automaton and the proportion of accepting paths is $1$ for every string in $L$.  However, you could make a nondeterministic automaton from that DFA by adding a million rejecting states and nondeterministic transitions from every "real" states to every one of these rejecting states. The proportion of accepting states for that machine is $1000001^{-|w|}$ for any string $w\in L$.